# Sum then delete one row - SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    Item VARCHAR(max),
    Qty DECIMAL(18,2),
    FixItem VARCHAR(max)
)
```

and here is some sample data

```
INSERT INTO #temp (Item, Qty, FixItem)
VALUES ('ItemRandom-1', -- Item - varchar(max)
        2, -- Qty - decimal
        'ItemA'  -- FixItem - varchar(max)
       )

INSERT INTO #temp (Item, Qty, FixItem)
VALUES ('ItemRandom-2', -- Item - varchar(max)
        5, -- Qty - decimal
        'ItemA'  -- FixItem - varchar(max)
       )          

INSERT INTO #temp (Item, Qty, FixItem)
VALUES ('ItemRandom-3', -- Item - varchar(max)
        5, -- Qty - decimal
        'ItemB'  -- FixItem - varchar(max)
       ) 

INSERT INTO #temp (Item, Qty, FixItem)
VALUES ('ItemRandom-4', -- Item - varchar(max)
        5, -- Qty - decimal
        ''  -- FixItem - varchar(max)
       )        

INSERT INTO #temp (Item, Qty, FixItem)
VALUES ('ItemRandom-5', -- Item - varchar(max)
        5, -- Qty - decimal
        ''  -- FixItem - varchar(max)
       )
```

Here is the result when you select it:

```
Item            Qty      FixItem
--------------------------------
ItemRandom-1    2.00     ItemA
ItemRandom-2    5.00     ItemA
ItemRandom-3    5.00     ItemB
ItemRandom-4    5.00     
ItemRandom-5    5.00
```

I want to group `FixItem` so I can sum the `Qty`, then delete one row between `ItemRandom-1` or `ItemRandom-2`

The result should be like this:

```
Item             Qty     FixItem
---------------------------------
ItemRandom-1     7.00     ItemA
ItemRandom-3     5.00     ItemB
ItemRandom-4     5.00     
ItemRandom-5     5.00
```

How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way. First update your table with total quantity for each `FixItem`. Then delete extra rows.

```
update a
    set a.Qty = b.Qty
from
    #temp a
    join (
        select
            FixItem, Qty = sum(Qty)
        from 
            #temp
        group by FixItem
    ) b on a.FixItem = b.FixItem

;with cte as (
    select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by FixItem order by Item) 
    from #temp
)

delete from cte
where rn > 1

select * from #temp
```

Output

```
Item            Qty     FixItem
--------------------------------
ItemRandom-1    7.00    ItemA
ItemRandom-3    5.00    ItemB
```

Edit:

```
update a
    set a.Qty = b.Qty
from
    #temp a
    join (
        select
            FixItem, Qty = sum(Qty)
        from 
            #temp
        where len(FixItem) > 0
        group by FixItem
    ) b on a.FixItem = b.FixItem

;with cte as (
    select *, rn = case when len(FixItem) > 0 then row_number() over (partition by FixItem order by Item) else 0 end
    from #temp
)

delete from cte
where rn > 1
```

Comment: I'm facing problem when there is two another rows with empty `FixItem`

Comment: How do you want to handle them? Show sample please

Comment: I already trying to add this `WHERE FixItem IS NOT NULL OR FixItem <> '' ` in the update part. But no help

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to achieve your result:

```
SELECT MIN(item) AS item,
    SUM(qty) AS qty,
    fixitem
FROM #temp
GROUP BY fixitem;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i prefer to delete one row instead of doing that

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an idea what you are looking for but for the instance as the desired result looking you would need `GROUP BY` clause and use `min()` function to get the first  `Item`, do not required to delete the item.

```
SELECT 
        MIN(Item) Item,
        SUM(Qty),
        FixItem
FROM #temp t
GROUP BY FixItem
```

For me delete would be unnecessary action as the result would display the sum of qty `7` but the actual would show the other rather then sum `7` for ItemRandom-1

```
DELETE t FROM
(
     SELECT *,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FixItem ORDER BY Item) Seq
     FROM #temp 
) t
WHERE Seq > 1
```

You could use window function in order to achieve the result

```
select  Item,
        SUM(Qty) OVER (ORDER BY FixItem  ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1 FOLLOWING) Qty,
        FixItem 
from #temp
```

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer. But i prefer to delete one row instead of doing that

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with select query, there is no need to delete records.
For this select query you can create view as well for easy access.

Based on requirement you can put either Min or Max in Item column.

```
select min(item) item, SUM(qty) qty, fixitem from #temp 
where fixitem != '' group by fixitem
union all
select item, qty, fixitem from #temp 
where fixitem = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) statement?

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(
  Item VARCHAR(max),
  Qty DECIMAL(18,2),
  FixItem VARCHAR(max)
);

INSERT INTO #temp(Item, Qty, FixItem)
  VALUES
    ('ItemRandom-1', 2, 'ItemA'),
    ('ItemRandom-2', 5, 'ItemA'),
    ('ItemRandom-3', 5, 'ItemB'),
    ('ItemRandom-4', 5, ''),
    ('ItemRandom-5', 5, '');

WITH
  t AS (
    SELECT *,
      SUM(Qty)OVER(PARTITION BY FixItem) t,
      ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY FixItem ORDER BY Item) n
    FROM #temp
    WHERE FixItem != ''
  )
MERGE t USING (SELECT * FROM t WHERE n = 1) s
  ON t.Item = s.Item AND t.FixItem = s.FixItem AND t.n = s.n
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.Qty = s.t
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE
OUTPUT $action, deleted.*;

SELECT * FROM #temp;
```

The results can be investigated at [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/XWMI81705).

The [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) clause is used for demo of capabilities of the MERGE statement.